# Magento 2 space symbols in storefront error messages are replaced with plus characters

Tags: magento2, bug

Does any one have the same question?
I saw this bug cannot be corrected by Magento.
Link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-commerce.html
[image: Storefront Demo]
The message code shows below and doesn't include plus(+) characters:

```
catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
```

I wanna ask is it possible to solve and how? anyone sloved?

Comment: you change error msg for login page???

Comment: all of error message are placed to "+".I shows the one of message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing plus symbols (+ symbols) in info or error messages instead of space characters in Magento 2, it is probably because you are using PHP version 7.4.2.

This bug is a PHP bug according to Magento. Try changing to a different version of PHP. See the known issues section [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-commerce.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can override this file on your theme for the solve this issue.
do below changes in **prepareMessageForHtml** function in messages.js file.
[image]
/app/design/frontend/Themevendor/themename/Magento_Theme/web/js/view/messages/messages.js